# DROOLS- version 6.5 compatibility with java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, drools

We are upgrading tomcat version to 9.0.35 which is compatible with Java 8. We are using DROOL KIE web container war 6.5 which is deployed in tomcat. So question here is are these versions compatible.

Java 8 - KIE war 6.5 - Tomcat 9.0.3.

We have tried it in non-production environment and  result looks fine. But since documentation of Drools is not clear we need this confirmation.

Comment: I ran a Drools 5 application in a Java 8 server. The restriction is that you can't put Java 8 code into your DRL, but Java 8 can be the JDK on the server.

Comment: Great! Thank you

Comment: Note that I was using the mvel dialect in my rules. If you've not explicitly declared a dialect, or are using Java dialect, some people have had issues running older Drools on Java 8. I stood up a proof of concept Drools 5.0 app just now on a Java 8 server and it was fine with mvel dialect, but had problems in Java dialect. Something to keep in mind.